# Puppeteer error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer on Google App Engine with Node.JS

whenever I run puppeteer on app engine, I encounter an error saying

Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!

This works fine in local environment, so I am guessing it is a problem with app engine.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    headless: true,
    args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--no-sandbox"],
});
```

This is my app engine's app.yaml file

```
runtime: nodejs12

env: standard

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

-- EDIT--

It works when I add `--disable-dev-shm-usage` argument, but then it always timeouts. Here are my codes.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  headless: true,
  args: [
    "--disable-gpu",
    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "--no-first-run",
    "--no-zygote",
    "--single-process",
  ],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

try {
  const url = "https://seekingalpha.com/market-news/1";
  const pageOption = {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    timeout: 20000,
  };

  await page.goto(url, pageOption);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
  return resolve("error at 1");
}

try {
  const ulSelector = "#latest-news-list";
  await page.waitForSelector(ulSelector, { timeout: 30000 });
} catch (e) {
  // ALWAYS TIMEOUTS HERE!
  console.log(e);
  await page.close();
  await browser.close();
  return resolve("error at 2");
}
...
```

Comment: Do you know the exact Node.Js 10.x version on App Engine? From puppeteer 3+ Node 10.18.1+ is the requirement and can cause issues if you are using older version.

Comment: @theDavidBarton it was 10.14.2, so I actually changed the runtime to nodejs12, Now it is on v12.16.3, but making a same error

Comment: This issue occurs for more App Engine and AWS Lambda users: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3927 Adding `--single-process` and/or `--no-zygote` makes it any better? If not you can give a try to all of these args: https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda/blob/master/source/index.js#L84 Let me know if it solves the issue and I can explain in details.

Comment: @theDavidBarton I have already tried --single-process. I will try other options and see what happens.

Comment: @theDavidBarton I have tried many other combinations, but still no luck

Comment: I see. If you tried putting all the flags (no need for specific combinations, you can launch puppeteer with 20+ flags) then it can be related to the script. Make sure to try `'--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess'` included, that is a regular culprit on App Engine. If it is possible can you show more of your puppeteer script? Maybe there is something that takes more time in App Engine than in local and the browser instance closes earlier than your script would finish. (typically forEach loops inside the script, or a not awaited puppeteer command)

Comment: @theDavidBarton Actually, if I add "--disable-dev-shm-usage", it runs. However, then it always timeout when page.waitForSelector. Again, it works fine in local with those arguments.

Comment: @theDavidBarton I added my codes in the question.

Comment: replacing your `pageOption` to `waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"` (removing the timeout in both the goto and waitForSelector) improves on the failure?

Comment: @theDavidBarton I finally found a solution.. It was about memory capacity. Thank you for help.

Comment: Great news! :) I am glad you've found the solution.

Comment: I had the same issue. Solution of HumbleCoder was really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems the problem was app engine's memory capacity.

When memory is not enough to deal with puppeteer crawling,

It automatically generates another instance.

However, newly created instance has a different puppeteer browser.

Therefore, it results in `Navigation failed because browser has disconnected`.

The solution is simply upgrade the app engine instance so it can deal with the crawling job by a single instance.

default instance is F1, which has 256M of memory, so I upgraded to F4, which has 1GB of memery, then it doesn't show an error message anymore.

```
runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F4

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

Comment: just a question ? where to put the code you provided ?

Answer (score 3):

For me the error was solved when I stopped using the `--use-gl=swiftshader` arg.

It is used by default if you use `args: chromium.args` from `chrome-aws-lambda`

Comment: tried other's solutions. None of them worked, then found your answer. Now its working flawlessly !

Comment: Worked for me also using `@sparticuz/chromium`!

Answer (score 0):

I was having that error in a deploy, the solution for this problem is change some parameters in `waitForNavigation`:

```
{ waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" , timeout: 60000 }
```