# Puppeteer 5.2.1 Error Running on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, puppeteer, p5.js

I'm having a hard time debugging an issue.

I'm getting the good old

```
Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
```

Running this script:

```
async function serveScriptResult(){
  try {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
      width: 800,
      height: 800,
      deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    });
    await page.goto('https://artblockstest.uc.r.appspot.com/generator/1000000');
    const image = await page.screenshot();
    await browser.close();
    return image;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

The page being opened is a relatively simple js.

Runs fine on my local server.

But not when deployed to Google Cloud.

Here's the thing that's throwing me off though. If you visit the Puppeteer "try it" link on their Github:

https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/

And replace the example.com url with the URL I'm trying to load, it works just fine. And it looks like they're hosting on Google Cloud as well.

[Snapshot of Puppeteer Example Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh0zM.png)

I'm Running node10 on the Google Cloud instance.

This is my first stack exchange post so please go easy on me! Let me know if there are additional details I can provide.

I have been following some issues with Puppeteer on Google Cloud for a couple of months. It looks like those have been resolved. Now I'm just stuck on this one :)

Thanks!

Comment: Digging deeper I've found that I can't access anything on my local server through puppeteer. If I change the code above to page.goto('http://example.com') it works, but anything local whether using 'http://localhost:'+PORT+'/' or full path (as in the original code above) returns an error.

Comment: It seems link [1] could be helpful for you as we are having similar error messages and there is a solution which could work for you. [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62891633/puppeteer-error-navigation-failed-because-browser-has-disconnected